# Shopify Custom Free Shipping Text

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

How can I dynamically display a small sign indicating free shipping for products with a shipping fee of 0, specifically tailored to the customer's location? This requires checking the shipping price and location for each product and displaying the free shipping sign wherever the product is shown.

In the shopify store setup, free shipping is offered to all products within specific shipping zones. However, I encountered an issue while trying to access the shipping price of an item on the product page to write my conditional using a custom liquid code. It seems that the shipping price may only be accessible on the cart page.